# Puerto en dotenv no funciona

Tags: typescript

Hola gente como estan? Soy nuevo en backend y no tengo mucha idea pero el caso es el siguiente, tengo que hacer una api que tenga dotenv. Instale dotenv, cree el .env y dentro de el escribi PORT=8080, luego en el archivo index.ts escribi:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env.PORT);
```

cuando guarde el archivo este dio undefined en vez de mostrar el puerto.
estoy usando nodejs, typescript, nodemon y tsc -w.
tengo tambien un archivo llamado server dentro de una carpeta models. el archivo server.ts contiene lo siguiente:

```
import express, {Express} from 'express';

export class Server {
    app: Express
    port: string | number | undefined

    constructor(){
        this.app = express();
        this.port = process.env.PORT;
    }

    listen():void{
        this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log(`Puerto ${this.port}`);
            
        });
    }
}
```

porfavor denme una manita. saludos!

Comment: Creo que en las versiones nuevas de nodejs puedes exportar directo con un set para windows y un export linux pero no lee directamente el .env en ese caso requieres instalar el modulo dotenv y la configuracion es require('dotenv').config();

Answer (score 0):

El problema me parece que es de sincronia al cargar las variables de entorno, debes esperar a que la carga de las variables mediante `dotenv.config()` primeramente, para esto puedes usar `async`, realiza el siguiente cambio :

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express, {Express} from 'express';

dotenv.config();

async function startServer() {

    console.log('Inicia');

    const app: Express = express();
    const port: string | number | undefined = process.env.PORT;

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Puerto ${port}');
    });
}

startServer();
```

Comment: no se si sera eso, cuando hice el console log (process.env.PORT) me dio undefined, ese es el problema. Al parecer el problema es de mi pc, pero no se que sea

Comment: Es que primero se debe llamar dotenv.config();  que es asincrono, debes asegurar que hasta que termine ahora si puedes obtener el valor de process.env.PORT, por eso te sugiero usar Async